# Docker container disappears without notice

Tags: docker, dokku

I host my webapplication is a docker container using Dokku.

Sometimes (maybe every 1-2 days) the docker container just disappears (doesnt show when `docker ps`) and as a result, my server goes down.

I haven't been able to find the cause.

I am looking for a way to debug this, any ideas?

Comment: Does it show in `docker ps -a`?

Comment: Ah yeah, didn't know that flag. It shows as `Exited (255) 4 hours ago  `

Comment: Dokku Maintainer here: You should checkout the `docker logs` output (as mentioned in a comment below) and also you might want to figure out if your application is segfaulting for some reason. Our upcoming release will have [restart-policy management](https://github.com/dokku/dokku/pull/2290), though you can always add restart policies using the official [docker-options plugin](http://dokku.viewdocs.io/dokku/advanced-usage/docker-options/) directly.

Comment: Logs didn't show anything unusual unfortunately. Any soft ETA on restart-policy management?

Answer (score 8):

The [Docker logs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/logs/) will give you the stdout and stderr for the container. Your application may or may not provide useful information here.

```
docker logs <containerid_or_name>
```

The Docker daemon can manage a long running container for you with a [`--restart`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#/restart-policies-restart) policy.

```
docker run --restart=always <image>
```

Answer (score 3):

Your application server has crashed apparently for whatever reason. you can see why with using `docker logs {container_id}` . also to prevent your application from going down in the future use `--restart=always` with your docker run so it will restart automatically on each crash